# CSS modified box and text

Tags: css, wordpress

Can css do this thing? and if yes what do you call this? thanks. I'm new in css [image: text wrap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "this" but I guess you meant something like this:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

span {
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>About us</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by html

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

the source link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .item{
        border:2px solid black;
        border-top:0px;
    
    }
    h2 {
       width: 100%; 
       text-align: center; 
       border-bottom: 2px solid #000; 
       line-height: 0.1em;
       margin: 10px 0 20px; 
    } 
    
    h2 span { 
        background:#fff; 
        padding:0 10px; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="item">
    <h2 class="left"><span>about us</span></h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I get help of `position`s for solve this question!*

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: red;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span>Enter Name</span>
   <input type="text">
</div>
```